# Achieve Intellisense in VS Code for my own JS ES6 modules libraries

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

VS Code Intellisense is indeed very helpful for working with internal project files, offering us autocompletion and even exploiting the written JSDoc.

However, I am working on different JS projects that depend on custom-made JS libraries (ES6 modules with Bitbucket Cloud repositories, retrieved via NPM or Yarn).

Naturally, I would like to benefit from Intellisense for those libraries as well, as I know that JSDoc is available. But sadly, I can't seem to find a way.

I tried to explicitly include files from my library in jsconfig.json, to no avail :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "node_modules/my-lib/**/*"]
}
```

Is there a simple way to tell VS Code to take into account my library files ?
As I understand, one way to achieve this would be to write and publish typescript definition files for each library. However, I feel like I'm missing something, and that surely VS Code must be able to handle my library JS file, just like it handles internal project files.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now, but I recently had the same issue.  Here is what I came up with.

As you mentioned, one way is to create a types declaration file.  Fortunately you can do this from your jsdoc comments with the [tsd-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd-jsdoc) package.

I added the following script to package.json to build the types file ...

```
jsdoc -r src -t node_modules/tsd-jsdoc/dist -d lib
```

This will create a `lib/types.d.ts` file.

Add a `types` entry to your package.json pointing to this file.

Make sure this is run as part of your prepublishOnly script so that the file is up-to-date when you run `npm publish`.

Generally, my src/index.js file just consists of several `export { default as thing } from './thing';` lines.   In order to get a proper declaration file that vscode could read, I had to format the file like so ...

```
/** @module my-module */

export { default as thing1 } from './thing1';
export { default as thing2 } from './thing2';
```

And then in the thing1 and thing2 jsdoc comments for the export add `@memberof module:my-module`, for example ...

```
/**
 * Thing 1
 * @param {string} thing
 * @memberof module:my-module
*/
function thing1(thing) {
}

export default thing1;
```